# Two divergent sequences such that their product converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Example of two divergent sequences such that their product converges.

I know, if $x_n=\left\{(-1)^n\right\}$ and  $y_n=\left\{(-1)^{n+1}\right\}$, then their product converges to $(-1)$. But here $x_n$ and $y_n$ are oscillatory sequences, they are not properly divergent(i.e. they do not diverge to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.

I want to know, are there two 'properly' divergent sequences so that their product converges? Please anyone help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Properly divergent sequences are unbounded sequences. Argue, can product of two unbounded sequences be bounded ever ?

Comment: For you, a “properly divergent sequence” is a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lvert x_n\rvert=\infty$? Or is it an unbounded sequence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your question is no.

If two sequences diverge to plus or minus infinity the absolute value of products are unbounded.

Since a convergent sequence is necessarily bounded the product of two properly divergent sequences is not convergent.

Comment: Ok, Thank you Sir.